# Use cx-freeze to create an msi that adds a shortcut to the desktop

Tags: windows-installer, cx-freeze

I am using cx-freeze to create an MSI installer for a Python application. How can I install a link to the application from the desktop?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use cx-freeze to create an msi installer that installs a child installer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733405/use-cx-freeze-to-create-an-msi-installer-that-installs-a-child-installer)

Comment: The questions are different. In this question, I want to create a desktop icon. The other question asks about bundling several MSI installers.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

To create a shortcut to the application, give the **shortcut_name** and **shortcut_dir** options to the Executable. The **shortcut_dir** can name any of the [System Folder Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/property-reference#system-folder-properties) (thanks Aaron). For example:

```
from cx_Freeze import *

setup(
    executables = [
        Executable(
            "MyApp.py",
            shortcut_name="DTI Playlist",
            shortcut_dir="DesktopFolder",
            )
        ]
    )
```

You can also add items to the MSI Shortcut table. This lets you create multiple shortcuts and set the working directory (the "start in" setting of the shortcut).

```
from cx_Freeze import *

# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371847(v=vs.85).aspx
shortcut_table = [
    ("DesktopShortcut",        # Shortcut
     "DesktopFolder",          # Directory_
     "DTI Playlist",           # Name that will be show on the link
     "TARGETDIR",              # Component_
     "[TARGETDIR]playlist.exe",# Target exe to exexute
     None,                     # Arguments
     None,                     # Description
     None,                     # Hotkey
     None,                     # Icon
     None,                     # IconIndex
     None,                     # ShowCmd
     'TARGETDIR'               # WkDir
     )
    ]

# Now create the table dictionary
msi_data = {"Shortcut": shortcut_table}

# Change some default MSI options and specify the use of the above defined tables
bdist_msi_options = {'data': msi_data}

setup(
    options = {
        "bdist_msi": bdist_msi_options,
    },
    executables = [
        Executable(
            "MyApp.py",
            )
        ]
    )
```

Comment: Would you know how this works with a system administrator going to install such an app? They won't get the option for shortcuts or will they?

Comment: The shortcut will be installed for all users if the ALLUSERS property is set.

Comment: Where can you set that ALLUSERS property? How do you specify an icon?

Comment: One way to set ALLUSERS is to add "ALLUSERS=1" to the msiexec command line when installing the .MSI.

Comment: Here's a list of Windows folders which you can use with shortcutDir: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370905(v=vs.85).aspx#System_Folder_Properties

Comment: @joshuanapoli Can it there be two key values?

Comment: @Har Yes, you can create multiple desktop shortcuts by adding multiple items to the shortcut_table list. Use a different "shortcut" name for each item.

Comment: Does somebody know how to set the icon for the shortcut? A string at the anotated line doesn't do the trick for me.

Comment: At least in my case the absolut path was needed. Hope that for the shortcut icon. I hope that helps someone.