# How to make Tkinter application show in Application Launcher

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, cx-freeze

I made an application in Tkinter. And created an MS installer using [cx_freeze](https://pypi.org/project/cx-Freeze/).

I want this app in `Desktop` **AND** `Application Launcher`. But this app is not visible in Application Launcher. We can set it in only one place. I have enabled the app on the desktop.

I want my app here. In the same way, Spotify and sublime are visible. See the image
[image]

Comment: I think all of those apps (or at least shortcuts to those apps) are in this folder: `C:\Users\TheLizzard\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` as well as in here: `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`. So I thing you should put a shortcut to your app there.

Comment: No, not all of them I can see are visible here.

Comment: For my Windows installation that is where all of the installed apps go. In one of those 2 folders. There are some apps (I think the built in windows apps) like Microsoft store that I can't find in those 2 folders but I think Windows is the one that handles them directly

Comment: @TheLizzard Any ideas, how can I add my program here during installation?

Comment: Just create a shortcut to your program and place that shortcut in one of those 2 folders. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26986470/create-shortcut-files-in-windows-7-using-python) should also work on Windows 10

Comment: Yes, I did that. But, I want to do it dynamically for all users that install my exe.

Comment: So read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26986470/create-shortcut-files-in-windows-7-using-python) and add something similar to your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232563/discussion-between-ajinzrathod-and-thelizzard).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding start menu shortcuts with cx\_Freeze installer for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16093129/adding-start-menu-shortcuts-with-cx-freeze-installer-for-python)