# How to package third party tools in a MSI using msitools?

Tags: windows-installer, msitools

My primary development platform is OSX. However from time to time I have to deploy some applications to some window machines.

The bespoke application has some dependency on python runtime and python win32 package. I want to make these installation as easy as possible.

That's why I am looking into using [`msitools` from GNOME](https://wiki.gnome.org/msitools)

My goal is to be able to include and trigger the installation of various windows application dependency via a single custom MSI file.

However I have checked the documentations here https://wiki.gnome.org/msitools/HowTo/CreateMSI and here https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/. I don't see how I can achieve my goal.

My question:

What xml markup can let me include and trigger an installation of third party components such as python installer as part of the overall installation process?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27521546/62576 might help, although it's not msitools related.

Comment: It is a good starting point! At least I know which tag to look for in SO. (`wix`)

Comment: The accepted answer to that question shows exactly what the MSI XML should look like to add a third-party tool (a bundle).