# unhandled child Wix node Bundle

Tags: macos, wix, msitools

I am trying to create a msi with [`msitools`](https://wiki.gnome.org/msitools) on OSX.

Here is my simple xml file

```
<Bundle Name="some-cool-name-for-the-whole-thing"
    Version="1.0"
    UpgradeCode="your-guid-here">

<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense">
    <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
        LicenseUrl=""
        ShowVersion="yes"/>
</BootstrapperApplicationRef>
  <Chain>
    <ExePackage Id="some_id"
          SourceFile="path-to-the-setup.exe">
      <CommandLine InstallArgument="/s " />
    </ExePackage>

    <MsiPackage Id="some-other-id-here"
      SourceFile="path-to-the-MSI-you-made-for-your-app">
    </MsiPackage>
  </Chain>
</Bundle>
```

It is based on the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42102377/58129

I have installed `msitools` using `brew`. The version of `msitools` is 0.97.

I run the following command

```
 wixl main.xml -o main.msi
```

and I get this error:

```
(wixl:28560): wixl-ERROR **: wix.vala:218: unhandled child Wix node Bundle
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I have tried to further simplify the xml to

I still get the same error message

Is there any problem with my xml file? Or did I invoke the command incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wixl doesn't support bundles. You can see the source code over at https://github.com/GNOME/msitools/tree/master/tools/wixl.